# What inequalities similar Lagarias' statement are easy to prove?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $$H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n},$$ the **nth harmonic number** and $$\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d,$$ **the sum of divisor function**, for example $\sigma(6)=12$.

I believe that this could be a nice problem in analysis.

> **Question.**  For which integer $M\geq 3$ can you claim easily, without assuming **Riemann Hypothesis**, that previous arithmetical functions satisfies 
>   $$\sigma(n)\leq H_n+M^{H_n}\cdot\frac{\log H_n}{\log M},$$
>   for all $n\geq 1$?

In a phrase, what is the minimum integer $M\geq e$ that satisfies a modified [Lagarias' statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), and it is easily to prove, unconditionally, with analysis?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330077/a-group-theoretic-interpretation-of-lagarias-inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the formulation you want with $M,$ $M=3$ works, indeed any real $M > e$ works.

Lemma 3.1 in Lagarias is, for $n \geq 3,$

$$ e^\gamma n \log \log n \leq \exp (H_n) \log (H_n) $$

Formula (2.2), Robin showed, unconditionally, for $n \geq 3,$
$$ \sigma(n) <  e^\gamma n \log \log n + 0.6482 \frac{n}{\log \log n}. $$

Without using the extra $H_n$ at all, we get
$$ \sigma(n) <   \exp (H_n) \log (H_n) + 0.6482 \frac{n}{\log \log n}. $$

If we include the $H_n,$ formula (3.7) is, this time for $n \geq 20,$
$$ H_n +  \exp (H_n) \log (H_n) \leq   e^\gamma n \log \log n  + \frac{7n}{ \log n}.$$

Comment: Thanks @WillJagy I understand, then that it is easy to compute numerically the least $M$ such that

$$H_n +M^{H_n}\cdot\frac{\log H_n}{\log M} \leq e^\gamma n \log \log n + \frac{7n}{ \log n}?$$

Comment: @JuanLG sure, the only reason to have $M > e$ is very small $n.$ I would keep $M=e$ and say some formulation you like works for $n > n_0,$ then explicitly find $n_0$ by computer, as all these bounds are effective (we know when they begin to be true)

Comment: Then very thanks much @WillJagy

Comment: @JuanLG The conditions of Lagarias and of Robin got more popular as elementary equivalents of RH, bu the most interesting to compute with is the original condition of Nicolas, http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/  and item number 84 at http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/publications.html

Comment: Very thanks much, when I read another time your answer I see more clearly. Very thanks much for references too @WillJagy